# How to remove unwanted space in flot chart

Tags: javascript, flot

[image]I am using flot.js for creating chart and am getting unwanted space.How can i remove that.

```
var DataSet1 = [ 
                 [new Date("2013/01/02").getTime(), 30],
                [new Date("2013/02/03").getTime(), 16 ],
                [new Date("2013/03/04").getTime(), 32 ],
                [new Date("2013/04/05").getTime(), 189],
                [new Date("2013/05/06").getTime(),  192],
                [new Date("2013/06/06").getTime(),  154],
                [new Date("2013/07/06").getTime(),  336],
                [new Date("2013/08/06").getTime(),  203],
                [new Date("2013/09/06").getTime(),  366],

        ];


    var chartColor = $(this).parent().parent().css("color");

                $.plot($("#chart-revenue1"),[ { data: DataSet1} ] ,{
                xaxis: 
                    { mode: "time", 
                    min: (new Date("2013/01/01")).getTime(),
                    max: (new Date("2013/08/01")).getTime(),
                    timeformat: "%d/%m/%y",
                    ticks: [new Date("2013/01/01").getTime(),new Date("2013/02/01").getTime(),new Date("2013/03/01").getTime(),new Date("2013/04/01").getTime(),new Date("2013/05/01").getTime(),new Date("2013/06/01").getTime(),new Date("2013/07/01").getTime() ],
                    minTickSize :30
                    }
                ,yaxis: {
                      min:0, max: 400,  tickSize: 50 
                    },
                     series: {
                       label: "Revenue",
                       lines: { 
                            show: true,
                            lineWidth: 3, 
                            fill: true
                       },
                       shadowSize: 0,
                   },
                    grid: {backgroundColor: { colors: ["#ffffff", "#f4f4f4"] }},
                   colors: ["#294777"],
                   legend: {
                        show: true
                   }

        });![enter image description here][2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your x axis min value. You have set it to:

```
min: (new Date("2013/01/01")).getTime(),
```

But your first data point is

```
new Date("2013/01/02").getTime()
```

So, a day later.

Comment: ya thanks.Now i understood why am getting space.But i guess it doesn't a error.The Date just starting with given values

Comment: And i have one more doubt.Can i put one common label for axis. Which means under xaxis labels one more label like "Stacks by Months"

Comment: Looks like you'll need to use a plugin: https://github.com/markrcote/flot-axislabels